# How to pass data from Electron to HTML

Tags: javascript, electron

I created a new electron app.

1. In index.js I Load data with the node file System.

```
app.on("ready", ()=>{
   createWindow();
   //data is just any big json object nothing special just static data
   const data = Loader.loadData();
 })
```

2. createWindow() just creates a window that loads index.html
3. In index.html I link to a script

```
<script defer src="main.js"></script>
```

4. How can i access the `const data` from main.js

If I try to use require in main.js it dosent work because its running on a diffrent Thread not inialized with node and more like an actual browser window. But is there any way of passing data from index.js to main.js

*Just an Idea have no idea if my concept of the Problem is even partially right*

If you need more Code or Information just ask!

Answer (score 0):

you can use module.export (see this [article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/))

in your main.js

```
let data;
app.on("ready", ()=>{
    createWindow();
    //data is just any big json object nothing special just static data
    data = Loader.loadData();
})

// Export so you can access it from the renderer thread
module.exports.getData = () => data;
```

In your index.html

```
<script>
    const {getData} = require('electron').remote.require('./main.js');
    console.log(getData());
</script>
```